# Web.config www rewrite if no subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

Does anyone know how to modify the rewrite rule below to only add a preceding www if no subdomain exists?

```
<rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this and tested it on our IIS 7.5 box.  It only adds the "www." if there is no sub-domain.

```
<rule name="Redirect naked domains (that do NOT have a custom sub-domain) to www.domain.com" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\." />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*\..*\.com" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```